# Zend Json encoding and using in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework.
My task is to send `JSON` data from controller to `Javascript`.
I have an simple array:

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
```

After i am encoding this array to json format:

```
$jsonData = Zend_Json::encode($array);
```

But I don't know, how I can get this data in `Javascript`. I send an ajax request with `jQuery`. And in success I am trying to alert data.

Note:
If I do `die($jsonData);` in the Controller all good.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use
 `$this->_helper->json($array);`
 instead of
 `$jsonData = Zend_Json::encode($array);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Zend Framework, but in simple php it can be done like this:

on the server, just do

```
 echo $jsondData;
 flush();
```

on the client use this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/